# Are the tags "projective-spaces" and "projective-geometry" synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tagging

From their tag descriptions, it sounds like [projective-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projective-space) and [projective-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projective-geometry) are synonyms.

On the other hand, I could imagine in theory how they could be differentiated (namely one doesn't necessarily have to explicitly reference the geometry of projective space at all times while studying it).

On a third hand, people might not be likely to obey such a distinction in practice, and questions concerning the geometry of projective spaces might predominate over questions concerning other aspects of them (I don't know if this is true or not).

And on a fourth hand, perhaps it might be useful to have the two tags merged so there is a larger community surrounding them. Or maybe it might not be useful for literally the exact same reason (e.g. the people studying the geometry of projective spaces could drown out those studying their other aspects).

An example of when people seem to benefit from having similar tags being separated is "probability" and "probability-theory", for example, so this might also be the situation here -- in any case, it is not clear to me what the etiquette surrounding these two projective tags is from their tag descriptions, which is why I wanted to bring it to your attention.

Anyway, I am not sure if this is something which other people have noticed before, so perhaps anyone who is an expert in either of these areas (I am not an expert in either of them) would be interested to know that both these two very similar tags exist. Again, I am not sure of anything.

Comment: They definitely should not be synonyms. In a sense it's like making group-theory a synonym of universal-algebra.

Comment: @MattSamuel OK, so to make sure I don't use them incorrectly again in the future, which of the two is the more general tag? Keep in mind that most of my questions stem from a _very_ introductory algebraic geometry book.

Comment: That's the thing, universal algebra is *not* more general than group theory, but it sounds like it is. They're simply different topics.

Comment: @MattSamuel Oh ok oops. So if I have a question about $\mathbb{CP}^1$ or $\mathbb{CP}^2$, should I use (projective-geometry) or (projective-spaces)? Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: It's not a dumb question. From your notation it sounds like you should use projective-space. What broader subject does it belong to?

Comment: @MattSamuel I guess probably projective varieties in algebraic geometry, although I have only gotten to homogeneous cubic polynomials defined on those spaces (I also asked some questions about the topology of those spaces too)

Comment: Then I would tag it algebraic-geometry first and foremost, then you can add projective-space or projective-geometry. I'm not enough of an expert to know whether or not anybody you want to see your question would even be looking for the projective-geometry tag, but it technically applies. There's a Wikipedia article on it.

Answer (score 8):

The *projective-space* tag is---according to the description---about the *space of lines through the origin in some vector space* in geometry, so every *geometric* question that relates to $\mathbb{C}P^n$ or $\mathbb{R}P^n$ belongs there. No matter whether it's algebraic geometry, differential geometry, geometric topology, .... In particular, as already suggested by others, when you're asking a question about projective space in its incarnation as algebraic variety, use the algebraic-geometry tag first and then this one.

The *projective-geometry* tag, however, is rather concerned with [this kind of geometry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry). (It's the projective counter part to Euclidean geometry in the classical sense.) Therefore, a question about projective space as a model for projective geometry could tag both, projective-geometry and projective-space, but a question about [desargues' theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem), e.g., may only tag projective-geometry but not necessarily projective-space.

Answer (score 3):

Projective geometry could also refer to [projective differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_differential_geometry), which is a type of Cartan geometry. The typical model space for projective differential geometry is the projective sphere, and a projective differential geometry can be defined on any smooth manifold.

Comment: Even though projective differential geometry has 'projective geometry' in its name, the description of the Projective-Geometry tag doesn't seem to include projective differential geometry.